# Differences between "Green tick icons" & "Solid green circle with the white check mark" in OneDrive status column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync

When we sync our sharepoint online document libraries using OneDrive desktop app, we got these 2 icons inside the Status column:-

[image] [image]

i read this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-do-the-onedrive-icons-mean-11143026-8000-44f8-aaa9-6... but i am still confused about the differences between these 2 icons.. as in both icons we will have a local copy of the file that will be synced with the online version is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The green tick icon means it is locally available (stored on your device) and can be opened when offline but if you have Storage Sense enabled these files will become online only again after an amount of time that you have set.

The solid green circle with a white tick means the file will always will be available on your device if you are offline (stored locally). The Storage Sense policy would not make this file online only after a certain period of time.

More information can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-windows-10-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.. so we can only feel the differences only if we enable Storage Sense? is this correct?

Comment: That's what the documentation suggests. I would recommend users who want to guarantee that their file is always available offline that they use the "Always keep on this device" option.

Answer (score 1):

As is referred to the [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-windows-10-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e) mentioned:

If you right click on the file and select “**Always keep on this device**”, you get the second icon for the synced file. It takes up space on local drive of your machine and will be available via this folder under all circumstances.

If you do not select this option, then you get the first icon. The file works more like temporary files and will be automatically free from this device when you have **[Storage Sense](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-onedrive-and-storage-sense-in-windows-10-to-manage-disk-space-de5faa9a-6108-4be1-87a6-d90688d08a48)** configured.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.. so we can only feel the differences only if we enable Storage Sense? is this correct?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev Not really. Storage Sense on Windows 10 works as an alternate to the former “Disk Cleanup” (cleanmgr.exe), one kind of the plenty of cleanup tools on local device. So basically, if you have a cleanup tool (or something similar) working on your machine, the OneDrive files that are not set as “Always keep on this device” will automatically go back online. Think of it as cache on disk.